# How do I trigger a secondary, keyframed animation with a condition in Maya?

Tags: animation, triggers, conditional-statements, maya

**The hypothetical goal:**
An animation of a ball rolling down a sidewalk. As the ball rolls past each lamp post on its journey down the sidewalk a vine begins to grow up the lamp post.

**The starting point (two files):**

**File 1:**(parent) A scene file containing an active rigid body ball rolling down a passive rigid body sidewalk. The animation on this ball is subject to change by altering the placement of obstacles etc.

**File 2:**(child) A single polygon vine animation growing up a single polygon lamp post.

**The question:** Is it possible to place a number of references to the lamp post file in the parent scene file and then trigger the imbedded vineGrow animation as the ball rolls down the sidewalk? Almost as if upon satisfaction of the condition a "Trax clip" of the vineGrow animation is snapped to the current place in time.

Such as:

```
if((ballHasPassedMeCondition)&&(triggeredStatus=="NotTriggered")){
    beginSecondaryAnimation();
    triggeredStatus = "triggered";
}
```

Though this animation method is unnecessary for such a simple scene I would like to understand how this type of animation can be achieved for use in a more complex scene. In the more complex scene I don't want to have to worry about manually starting all this secondary animation and then restarting it when the driving animation changes.

Thanks

Comment: Its possible but not very practical. The problem with your question is that it doesn't specify a goal for how the trigger is to be implemented. Is it a onetime process or a dynamic one.

The problem with a dynamic animation of this kind is that it makes working with the scene hard. As you can now not jump back and forth in time and see any meaningful feedback. Form a workflow perceptive its better to choreograph things in sequences first fixing the dynamic then baking it down and baking in the other animation once. This way any other animation tweak you do is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting a driven key to the translate of the ball in whatever direction it is rolling down the hill and connecting that to the vine growth attribute.